# Direction of a Point in a Vector Field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, dynamical-systems

> Consider the system of first order ODEs
>   $$x'=x(y-1) \ \ y'=y(2-x^2-y). \tag{1}$$

For the equilibrium points $(\pm 1,1)$, these give stable spirals. I am trying to determine the direction of rotation of this spiral. I considered a point, $$(x,y)=(2,2),$$ and by substituting this into $(1)$, I found that $$x'>0, \  \ y'<0.$$
By constructing an arrow diagram as shown below, I believed that the point $(x,y)=(2,2)$ rotates anticlockwise (and hence the spiral rotates anticlockwise). But the solution in my books states this is in fact a clockwise rotation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x' \gt 0$ and $y' \lt 0$, the arrow on your diagram for the sum of the $2$ vectors should be in the opposite direction, i.e., to the lower right, and going clockwise, instead, just like your book says.

Comment: I see. May I ask why this is? I thought the convention was to place the arrows head to tail.

Comment: @Bell The convention is correct. As for what the final result is, you can consider the horizontal vector to be $(x',0)$ and the vertical vector to be $(0,y')$, so their sum is $(x',y')$. If you were to "start" at the upper left, i.e., what I believe you're calling the "head", then you would go to the tail of the horizontal vector, with it being the head of the vertical vector, then go down to the end of it where the arrow is, what I assume you're calling the "tail".

Comment: Apologies, the "tail' refers to the side with the arrow point. So what you're saying is that the resulting vector is that directed from the starting point (tail of the horizontal) to the end point (head of the vertical)?

Comment: @Bell You've drawn the black arrows correctly. With the sum of the $2$ vectors, i.e., the orange (if that it's colour) vector, it's head is at the same position as the head of the first vector, and it's tail postition is the same as that of the second vector. If you were to add $3$ or more vectors, then the resulting vector's head position would match the first vector's head position and it's tail position would match the last vector's tail position.

Comment: @Bell Here's another way to think about it which may help. Consider the arrows to show the direction of "motion". The $2$ black vectors show "motion" going to the right and then down. The sum of the $2$ vectors is the direct "motion" vector, with this being from the upper left to the lower right of the diagram and, thus, the arrow should be in the opposite direction. Does this help you understand it a bit better?

Comment: I think so, I'm just trying to generalise this. For example, if we found that $x'<0$ and $y'>0$, would this be an anticlockwise rotation?

Comment: @Bell If $x' \lt 0$ and $y' \gt 0$, then it would the opposite direction, i.e., as you stated, this would be an anti-clockwise rotation.

Comment: Similarly, if $x'<0$ and $y'<0$ then this would be anticlockwise and if $x'>0$ and $y'>0$ then this would be clockwise?

Comment: @Bell Yes, that is correct.

Comment: No, in the latter 2 cases you qualitatively move towards the stationary point or away from it. From this information alone one can not make any valid guess on the rotation orientation. Resp. this would more hint towards a source or sink without rotational component, not a center.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for stating that correction. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Bell As LutzL stated in the comment above, having x′ and y′ being negative or positive alone is not sufficient to determine a rotation orientation, and even if there is necessarily one. For example, if both are positive, then it's in a direction basically away from the origin and if both are negative, it's mainly going towards the origin. I was thinking of something somewhat different, so I'm sorry I missed that earlier, but it was quite late for me then (past $1$ a.m. my time) & I was tired.

Answer (score 1):

No, the vector field at $(2,2)$ should be $(2,-8)$, it is in the opposite direction with respect to your drawing. A better view is given in this picture:

$\hskip 1 in$[image]

Note that the spirals around $(1,1)$ are clockwise, and, by symmetry, the spirals around $(-1,1)$ are anti-clockwise